# Scalable Text in Photoshop In a Droplet?

Tags: text, batch-processing, resize, actions

I'm trying to create a droplet for batch image processing that will put a border of 2 px all around, add 30 px to the top, then within that top space place some text that will automatically scale to the size of the pic, and center it. I've got all except the text added to an action, but fighting with the text issue: it doesn't place the text in the center and it doesn't scale it properly when I run various sized images through the droplet.

Is there a way I can do this?